# A mysterious .html() undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

html:

```
<div id="test1">test1</div>
```

js:

```
console.log($("#test1").html());
```

The codes can't be more simple I guess.

I have checked that no any other elements has the id "test1".
jQuery was included in the html for 
The mysterious thing is, `$("#test1").html()` always returns `undefined`.

Stucked for almost an hour now. Can anyone identify possible cause of this mysterious `undefined`?

Comment: can you show us complete source?

Comment: Did you actually link the js file?

Comment: Probably, you're executing the JS code before DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: does the `js` precede the `html`? or are you using `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you include more of your code we can't be 100% sure, what is probably going on is that your javascript is executed before the whole DOM is loaded and thus it can't find your div, try to wrap it around a ready callback:

```
$(function() {
    console.log($("#test1").html());
});
```